# Бан при нажатии клавиш

Tags: php, javascript

Как сделать чтобы по нажатии клавиш ctrl + u в пхп срабатывал код, который записывал в .htaccess айпи клиента, нажавшего эту кнопку?

Comment: Ну событие в JS, вроде keydown, keypress, а там AJAX-запрос к PHP-файлу (или к action, если таки MV*), и в этом файле в PHP получаем IP как обычно и пишем куда хотим. Но, во-первых, что-то я не уверен, что получится отследить именно эти клавиши, Ctrl системная же. Во-вторых, обходится же легко, особенно при написании бота. Любой специалист поможет страждущему решить  проблему.

Answer (score -1):

Писать в .htaccess ip адреса честно не очень удобно, лучше их заносить в бд, а потом сверять их
вот пример кода надеюсь он вам будет полезен 
**1. Сначало нужно создать таблицу в бд**

```html
CREATE TABLE `ip_block` (
 `id` INT(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `ip` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

**2. Сделать подключение к базе данных для этого мы будем использовать обёртку PDO пример файла *db.php***

```html
<?php 
    $host = 'localhost';
    $db   = 'ваша бд';
    $user = 'имя пользователя';
    $pass = 'ваш  пароль';
    $charset = 'utf8';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

3. Нужно создать сам идексный файл, который будет проверять есть-ли данный ip адрес в бд заблокированных пользователей если нет, то выводим нужнную страницу. И амое главное если пользователь нажал  Ctrl+U то мы его ip адрес отправляем в бд в ч/с. Далее выводим бесконечный цикл в котором выводится alert бесконечное количество раз. Это связанно с тем что пользователю не удалось открыть страницу view-source: . Когда он снова откроет сайт то увидит блок страницу. Сам файл index.php

```html
<?php

require_once 'db.php';

$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(ip) as ip FROM ip_block WHERE ip=:ip");
$stmt->bindParam(':ip', $ip);
$stmt->execute();
$block = $stmt->fetch();
if($block["ip"] > 0){
header('Location: /test/ban.php');
exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Пользователь ещё не нажал CTRL+U</h1>
</body>
</html>
<script>
var message="Правая кнопка мыши отключена!";
function click(e) {
   if (document.all) {    // IE
      if (event.button == 2) {    // Чтобы отключить левую кнопку поставьте цифру 1
          alert(message);    // чтобы отключить среднюю кнопку поставьте цифру 1
          return false;}
      }
   if (document.layers) { // NC
      if (e.which == 3) {
          alert(message);
          return false;}
      }
}
if (document.layers)
   {document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);}
document.onmousedown=click;
document.oncontextmenu=function(e){return false};




document.mousedown=function(e){ if(event.which == 3)        
        {          
            alert();
        }
}

let isCtrl = false;
document.onkeyup=function(e){ if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=false; }
document.onkeydown=function(e) {
    if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=true;
    if(e.which == 85 && isCtrl === true) {


let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();


xhr.open('GET', 'check.php', false);


xhr.send();

if (xhr.status != 200) {
  alert( 'что-то не работает' ); 
} else {
  location.reload();
}
let b = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < b; i++) {
 alert();
 b++;
}
 


    }
} 
</script>
</body>
</html>
</script>
```

4. Добавляем ip пользователя в бд файл check.php

```html
require_once 'db.php';

$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(ip) as ip FROM ip_block WHERE ip=:ip");
$stmt->bindParam(':ip', $ip);
$stmt->execute();
$block = $stmt->fetch();
if($block["ip"] > 0){
header('Location: /test/ban.php');
exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Пользователь ещё не нажал CTRL+U</h1>
</body>
</html>
<script>
var message="Правая кнопка мыши отключена!";
function click(e) {
   if (document.all) {    // IE
      if (event.button == 2) {    // Чтобы отключить левую кнопку поставьте цифру 1
          alert(message);    // чтобы отключить среднюю кнопку поставьте цифру 1
          return false;}
      }
   if (document.layers) { // NC
      if (e.which == 3) {
          alert(message);
          return false;}
      }
}
if (document.layers)
   {document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);}
document.onmousedown=click;
document.oncontextmenu=function(e){return false};




document.mousedown=function(e){ if(event.which == 3)        
        {          
            alert();
        }
}

let isCtrl = false;
document.onkeyup=function(e){ if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=false; }
document.onkeydown=function(e) {
    if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=true;
    if(e.which == 85 && isCtrl === true) {


let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();


xhr.open('GET', 'check.php', false);


xhr.send();

if (xhr.status != 200) {
  alert( 'что-то не работает' ); 
} else {
  location.reload();
}
let b = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < b; i++) {
 alert();
 b++;
}
 


    }
} 
</script>
</body>
</html>
</script>
```

5. Файл если пользователя  бан . Файл ban.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Умник ты забанен</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

[скачать zip архив https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WIRJsJF6YPi6IvV_HtreHFaxSp9BHoYL](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WIRJsJF6YPi6IvV_HtreHFaxSp9BHoYL)

[посмотреть видео https://youtu.be/5oKPTEXL2oU](https://youtu.be/5oKPTEXL2oU)

6. Ссылки на полезные статьи и документацию

[Введение в браузерные события - https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events](https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events)

[Виртуальные коды клавиш для javascript (event.keyCode) - http://umi-cms.spb.su/ref/javascript/251/](http://umi-cms.spb.su/ref/javascript/251/)

[Объекты данных PHP PDO - http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php#book.pdo](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php#book.pdo)

[Как работать с PDO? Полное руководство(очень полезно) - http://phpfaq.ru/pdo](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo)

[Информация о сервере и среде исполнения - http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php)

[Основы XMLHttpRequest - https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest)

Цикл (программирование) - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: Вы это серьёзно? На клиенте выполнять PHP? Про всё остальное я уже молчу.

Comment: Зачем делать не рабочий сниппет? @Deonis, на самом деле - это сервер, просто написано в перемешку и не совсем верно, а в основном это рабочий код.

Comment: @Deonis а это вообще возможно? Или это просто ошибка автора?

Comment: @And, ты издеваешься??

Comment: Я догадываюсь, что под фразой "_в основном это рабочий код_" имеет в виду @And )) Представим, что нет `fopen` с флагом `w`, который "убьёт" `htaccess` и на этом история бы закончилась. Коротко... Обращение к файлу (_заход на страницу_) `>` выполняется PHP сценарий. `Ctrl`+`U` `>` не во всех браузерах (*!*) это вызывает новый запрос `>` выполняется код PHP, как и в первом случае. Получается, что при любом обращении к файлу, будет выполняться сценарий на сервере.  (_продолжение ниже_)

Comment: Но тогда возникает вопрос - какой понт от JS-кода? Поместите PHP-код в любое другое место на странице и вы получите ровно такой же эффект. Кстати, в том же осле, сочетание `Ctrl`+`U` просто откроет код в блокноте и это лучшая демонстрация абсурдности предложенного варианта.
И @Telion, нет, это не возможно.

Comment: Уиии, минус. Пояснение: если Вы не знаете ответ, то, пожалуйста, воздержитесь от ответа, собьёте с Истинного пути новичка.

Comment: @Vadim, За всё время существования этого форума со времен hashcode.ru, я поставил всего один минус и он, как это не покажется странным, был адресован не вам..

Comment: @Other проверь код если не сработает то я в шоке

Comment: @Deonis ну в этом случае только я ответ дал

Comment: @Vadim, А Вы принципиальны. Даже видео есть. Но сути сайта ещё не поняли. Что ж, ещё не вечер, хочу верить.

Comment: Минусующим: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45202704#45202704

Comment: @Deonis, оказывается нет. Отвечающий внёс правку с остатками кода, которая проясняет ситуацию.

Comment: @Telion, отвечающий дополнил ответ. Всё правильно (идеологически). Просто в начале PHP-скрипт был обрезан так, что смахивал на чистый JS. Да ещё и в fiddle был запихнут.